# Installed django on hostgator(shared), but it's giving 404 error instead of showing Welcome page

Tags: django

I have installed Django on Hostgator shared plan.

I am able to access to mydomain.ca/admin (actually mydomain.ca/index.fcgi/admin), and able to login as superuser.

However, when I go to mydomain.ca, it displays

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://mydomain.ca/index.fcgi/
>   Using the URLconf defined in src.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>   ^admin/
>   The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
>   You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

If I'm correct, it should show "It worked!" website instead, since I have not added anything to my app yet.

I have followed the tutorial on http://support.hostgator.co.m/articles/django-with-fastcgi

My .htaccess looks exactly same as the one in the tutorial, and my index.fcgi looks like

.#!/home/user/mydjango/bin/python

import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/user/mydjango/source")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'src.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")

Could anyone assist me to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: It may be beyond your ability to control, but if you can, switch to WebFaction. You'll be a lot happier, and it's an order of magnitude easier to get a Django site running there.

Comment: What do you mean by beyond my ability to control? Isnt it supposed to be showing It worked! website?

Comment: What I meant was if the hosting choice wasn't up to you, like if your client already had an account at HostGator they were forcing you to use. Running a Django site on fcgi isn't what you want to be doing.

Comment: Facing the same problem